# Bind command to remove self from collection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to make a dynamic list box of text boxes, where the text boxes are added and removed by pressing buttons that are matched with each text box. I have everything working but the removal, which only occasionally works on the last item (but not always).

I have an `ObservableCollection<ExcludedPath>` where the `ExcludedPath` class is:

```
public class ExcludedPath : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Visibility _addButtonVisibility;
    private string _path;

    private ICommand _removeButtonCommand;
    private Visibility _removeButtonVisibility;

    public ICommand RemoveButtonCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _removeButtonCommand;
        }
        set
        {
            _removeButtonCommand = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public Visibility AddButtonVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            return _addButtonVisibility;
        }
        set
        {
            _addButtonVisibility = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Path
    {
        get
        {
            return _path;
        }
        set
        {
            _path = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand AddButtonCommand { get; set; }

    public Visibility RemoveButtonVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            return _removeButtonVisibility;
        }
        set
        {
            _removeButtonVisibility = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(
        [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(
            this,
            new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

In my `ViewModel` class, here are the relevant snippets:

```
internal ViewModel()
{
    SetUpProperties();
}

public ObservableCollection<ExcludedPath> ExcludedPaths { get;
    private set; }

private void AddExcludedPathExecute()
{
    ExcludedPaths.Add(new ExcludedPath());
}

private bool CanAddExcludedPath()
{
    return ExcludedPaths.All(x => !x.Path.IsNullOrWhiteSpace());
}

private bool CanRemoveExcludedPath()
{
    return ExcludedPaths.Count > 1;
}

private void OnExcludedPathsChanged(
    object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var addButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(
        AddExcludedPathExecute, CanAddExcludedPath);

    if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < ExcludedPaths.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            ExcludedPaths[i].AddButtonVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
        var excludedPath = ExcludedPaths.Last();
        excludedPath.AddButtonCommand = addButtonCommand;
        excludedPath.AddButtonVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        excludedPath.RemoveButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(
            () => RemoveExcludedPath(excludedPath), 
            CanRemoveExcludedPath);
    }
    else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
    {
        ExcludedPaths.Last().AddButtonVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}

private void RemoveExcludedPath(ExcludedPath excludedPath)
{
    ExcludedPaths.Remove(excludedPath);
}

private void SetUpProperties()
{
    ExcludedPaths = new ObservableCollection<ExcludedPath>();
    ExcludedPaths.CollectionChanged += OnExcludedPathsChanged;
    ExcludedPaths.Add(new ExcludedPath());
}
```

And my `View`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ExcludedPaths}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                    Content ="+"
                    Command="{Binding AddButtonCommand}"
                    Visibility="{Binding AddButtonVisibility}"/>
                <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                    Content="-"
                    Command="{Binding RemoveButtonCommand}"
                    Visibility="{Binding RemoveButtonVisibility}"/>
                <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                        Text ="{Binding Path, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When handling collection changed events you should not just get the last item like you did (`var excludedPath = ExcludedPaths.Last();`), but iterate over `e.NewItems`.

(Likewise on removal you should iterate over `e.OldItems`.)

---

Personally i handle removal in the object containing the list, though your approach should work. To do it my way you would bind it like this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

The item to remove is passed as command parameter.

Comment: Doesn't fix the issue. I can still only remove the last object, and that doesn't work consistently.

Comment: I thought it might have to do with wrong variable capturing, but the code does not really look it would do that. You could always try to do it differently though (see edit).

Comment: @MichaelBrandonMorris: Also, what do you mean by inconsistently? Does nothing happen upon click?

Comment: Yes, by inconsistently, I mean that with how I had it, clicking remove on the last item would sometimes trigger the command, and sometimes it wouldn't. It never worked on anything but the last item though. I'll try your edit.

Comment: @MichaelBrandonMorris's way is incorrect.  The correct way is as H.B. states--place the ICommands in the parent VM, send in the item being bound via CommandParameter, and remove it from the ObservableCollection.  Clean, neat, and you don't have twenty bazillion ICommands everywhere.

Comment: @MichaelBrandonMorris well, you might have accepted it for the first paragraph :)